# How do I remotely execute scripts on multiple servers, mix output

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, software-rec

Hi I'm looking for a piece of software or some sort of technique that would enable me to do following in one terminal window:

- Take as input a list of ssh-enabled machines with login, password and script path information, something like this:

  `login:pass@192.168.1.1/path/to/script/run.sh`
  `login:pass@192.168.1.2/path/to/script/run.sh`
- Open ssh connections to these machines and run the specified scripts remotely.
- Output from all the scripts should be piped to my local window.
- When I send a signal like Ctrl-C, I want to kill the remote scripts and then the connection. A massive plus would be if my machine goes down, the remote scripts are killed also.

A plus would be if I could use this in Cygwin terminal since that's what I use, but I'm open to anything that would get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using OpenSSH.  It is deliberately difficult to programatically give a password to ssh, because it's typically a bad idea.  Instead of using passwords, can you use [public key authentication](http://macnugget.org/projects/publickeys/)?  If so, the following should do the trick:

```
for cmd in login@192.168.1.1:/path/to/script/run.sh login@192.168.1.2:/path/to/script/run.sh; do
    ssh ${cmd%%:*} ${cmd#*:}
done
```

Comment: That would, actually, be one of those [moments were something like GNU parallel might be handy](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score 0):

You will need public key authentication, you will also need something like PSSH which is a  python based tool for running multiple parallel ssh sessions.

https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/

Answer (score 0):

If you can write Perl, you should check [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel).

It can log in the remote hosts using public key or password authentication and run the programmed tasks in parallel.